# Is it possible to run Google Page speed from the command line?

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, pagespeed

Is it possible to run Google Page speed from the command line?  If so, how?  I'm interested in automating nightly or daily Google PageSpeed calls that will inform me after a commit or daily if I've caused a drop in the Google PageSpeed 'grade' (for a given page).

Answer (score 16):

It's possible to use the [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v1/getting_started) from the command line:

Install via: 
`$ npm install --global psi`

Usage: 
`$ psi <url> --key=<key> --prettyprint=<true> --userIp=<userIp> --locale=<locale> --strategy=<desktop|mobile>`

Run it like this: `$ psi http://stackoverflow.com`

[image: PageSpeed Desktop Insights CLI]

Also for mobile insights: `$ psi http://stackoverflow.com --strategy=mobile`

[image: PageSpeed Mobile Insights CLI]

UPDATE: You can use the PageSpeed Insights within your local development environment (internet connection required) with [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) + [grunt-pagespeed](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-pagespeed) + [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/usage). Checkout the [sample project for grunt-pagespeed and ngrok](https://github.com/jrcryer/grunt-pagespeed-ngrok-sample) for further information.

Note: Run `$ ngrok -authtoken <your-token> 80` and check the web interface parameters to make sure to set the right port in your `Gruntfile.js`!

Comment: Darn, my original post isn't very clear.  I'd rather test these things before they go to production or acceptance, say in a nightly build, or just locally.  So no access via the internet to the instance unless it's ran from the command line, and can access localhost, ect.

Comment: @lucidquiet I've updated my answer and added an option for using PageSpeed in a local development environment. Not sure if this will work for you as it requires Grunt and an internet connection, but maybe you can give it a try :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Google Page Speed API](https://code.google.com/apis/pagespeedonline/v1/getting_started.html). It won't work directly from a command line but you can easily write a script in your language of choice that will interact with the API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *curl* to run *PageSpeed* from command line like so:

```
curl "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=http://your_url/&prettyprint=true&strategy=mobile&key=your_api_key"
```

It will return human readable results in json. cmd-F "score" to locate the overall score.

Reference : [Official Google api](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v2/first-app).

Comment: please not that the API is now at v5